# Why Python KafkaConsumer do not read all messages from topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

For test purposes I have to read all messages in some kafka topics. Before test I remove all messages using `/kafka-delete-records.sh` then I run tests that fill kafka topics. After test I want to analyse all messages.

My code to read all messages from all topic partitions:

```
def show_messageges_from_topic(kafka_server, topic):
    i = 0
    consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_server, auto_offset_reset='earliest')
    try:
        partitions = consumer.partitions_for_topic(topic)
        if partitions:
            for partition in partitions:
                tp = TopicPartition(topic, partition)
                consumer.assign([tp])
                consumer.seek(partition=tp, offset=0)
                records = consumer.poll(50)     # timeout in millis
                for _, consumer_records in records.items():
                    for consumer_record in consumer_records:
                        i += 1
                        msg_process(topic, i, consumer_record)
    finally:
        consumer.close()
    return i
```

For test purposes I created 1230 messages in two topics, one with one partition, and other with 4 partitions:

Counts from Kafka UI (webpage http://169.0.1.77:8090/ui/clusters/local/all-topics?perPage=25&q=fdp)

```
Topic Name  Partitions  Out of sync replicas    Replication Factor  Number of messages  Size

app.analyse 1   0   1   1230    12 MB   
app.result  4   0   1   1230    8 MB
```

But it seems that my code do not read all messages from topic with one partition:

My counts:

```
topic name {partitions} cnt

app.analyse {0}                  cnt=500
app.result {0, 1, 2, 3}          cnt=1230
```

What can I do to read all messages from kafka topics?

My environment:

```
[mn:~] $ python -V
Python 3.11.4

[mn:~] $ pip3 list | grep kafka
kafka-python       2.0.2
```

Comment: Why are you using assign instead of subscribe? And what consumer group are you using?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Isn't `subscribe()` for new messages, and `assign()` for already existing? If you use `assign()` then `group_id` is not usable. See 2nd note on https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.assign

Comment: Nope. Assign is for manually selecting one or more partitions. Subscribe reads all of them, as you're already trying to do. So I was curious what advantages / difference using assign was providing here

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried subsribe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77126835/how-to-enable-diagnostics-for-python-kafka-consumer and it works on some machines, and does not work on other machines.

Comment: Machine shouldn't matter. No two consumers in the same group cannot read the same partition, so that's something to consider. I suggest you explicitly seek to the beginning of the topics, not depend on auto.offset.reset to do that for you

Comment: So `consumer.seek(partition=tp, offset=0)` is ok? I tried both `assign()` and `subscribe()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132426/python-kafka-stange-difference-between-reading-from-kafka-topic-using-subscribe but results are very strange.

Comment: I had to change `poll()` usage. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132426/python-kafka-stange-difference-between-reading-from-kafka-topic-using-subscribe?noredirect=1#comment135977160_77132426