# How to enable diagnostics for python-kafka consumer?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have test cases that have to read from kafka topics. On some machines that works, but on machine dedicated for tests it simply ends without neither result nor error.

My code to read all message from kafka topic:

```
def show_messageges_from_topic(kafka_server, topic, date_filter, msg_id_list):
    i = 0
    consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_server, group_id=None, auto_offset_reset='earliest')
    try:
        consumer.subscribe([topic])
        while True:
            records = consumer.poll(50)     # timeout in millis
            if not records:
                break
            for _, consumer_records in records.items():
                for consumer_record in consumer_records:
                    i += 1
                    msg_process(topic, i, consumer_record, date_filter, msg_id_list)
    finally:
        consumer.close()
```

Using Kafka GUI I see that there are messages on topic I read.

On machine where it does not read messages I see that there is connection with Kafka:

```
[root@kafka-client ~]# netstat -anp | grep "\.77"
tcp        0      0 169.0.1.223:46282       169.0.1.77:9092         ESTABLISHED 680492/python3      
tcp        0      0 169.0.1.223:39088       169.0.1.77:9092         TIME_WAIT   -
```

Is there something wrong with my code? How to enable consumer diagnostics?

PS I tried to use `group_id` but then my program does not read any messages even on machines where reading works.

PS2: I had similar question:
[Why Python KafkaConsumer do not read all messages from topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77058106/why-python-kafkaconsumer-do-not-read-all-messages-from-topic)
where I tried to read from all partitions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "diagnostics". You're welcome to add logging to your own code, but I'm not familiar with "diagnostics" being part of any python library

Comment: @OneCricketeer by diagnostics I mean enabling debug log, checking topic status, checking network and others ways to know why on my test machine with network connection to kafka I cannot read messages.

Comment: I had to change `poll()` usage. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132426/python-kafka-stange-difference-between-reading-from-kafka-topic-using-subscribe?noredirect=1#comment135977160_77132426