# Strange difference between reading from kafka topic using subscribe() and assign()

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

My task is to count messages in Kafka topics (some with one partition, some with many partitions). I tried two techniques: one with `subscribe()` and other with `assign()`.

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kafka
from kafka.structs import TopicPartition


def count_messages(consumer):
    i = 0
    while True:
        records = consumer.poll(50)     # timeout in millis
        if not records:
            break
        for _, consumer_records in records.items():
            for _ in consumer_records:
                i += 1
    return i


def show_messageges_assign(kafka_server, topic):
    cnt = 0
    consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_server, group_id=None, auto_offset_reset='earliest', enable_auto_commit=False)
    try:
        partitions = consumer.partitions_for_topic(topic)
        if partitions:
            for partition in partitions:
                tp = TopicPartition(topic, partition)
                consumer.assign([tp])
                consumer.seek(partition=tp, offset=0)
                cnt += count_messages(consumer)
    finally:
        consumer.close()
    print('%s assign, partitions: %s, msg cnt=%d' % (topic, partitions, cnt))


def show_messageges_subscribe(kafka_server, topic):
    cnt = 0
    consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_server, group_id=None, auto_offset_reset='earliest', enable_auto_commit=False)
    try:
        consumer.subscribe([topic])
        cnt += count_messages(consumer)
    finally:
        consumer.close()
    print('%s, subscribe, msg cnt=%d' % (topic, cnt))


def test_topic(kafka_server, topic):
    show_messageges_assign(kafka_server, topic)
    show_messageges_subscribe(kafka_server, topic)
    print('')


def main():
    kafka_server = '169.0.1.77:9092'
    test_topic(kafka_server, 'gc.ifd.analyse.fdp')
    test_topic(kafka_server, 'gc.ifd.result.fdp')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Problems:

1. `subscribe()` do not work on some machines. On the same machine `assign()` work, but not very reliable.
2. `assign()` works on all test machines I have, but when there are many partitons I think it do not read from all partitions

Results:

After test there are 1435 messages in two topics. I can see them in web browser "UI for Apache Kafka".

Results on my 4 test machines:

Machine 1 and 2:

```
[root@test-kafka emulator]# python3 so_kafka_checker.py
gc.ifd.analyse.fdp assign, partitions: {0}, msg cnt=1435
gc.ifd.analyse.fdp, subscribe, msg cnt=1435

gc.ifd.result.fdp assign, partitions: {0, 1, 2, 3}, msg cnt=366
gc.ifd.result.fdp, subscribe, msg cnt=1435


[root@igg emulator]# python3 so_kafka_checker.py
gc.ifd.analyse.fdp assign, partitions: {0}, msg cnt=1435
gc.ifd.analyse.fdp, subscribe, msg cnt=1435

gc.ifd.result.fdp assign, partitions: {0, 1, 2, 3}, msg cnt=366
gc.ifd.result.fdp, subscribe, msg cnt=1435
```

Machine 3 and 4:

```
[mn: emulator] python3 so_kafka_checker.py
gc.ifd.analyse.fdp assign, partitions: {0}, msg cnt=1435
gc.ifd.analyse.fdp, subscribe, msg cnt=0

gc.ifd.result.fdp assign, partitions: {0, 1, 2, 3}, msg cnt=366
gc.ifd.result.fdp, subscribe, msg cnt=0


[root@test-gc emulator]# python3 so_kafka_checker.py
gc.ifd.analyse.fdp assign, partitions: {0}, msg cnt=1435
gc.ifd.analyse.fdp, subscribe, msg cnt=0

gc.ifd.result.fdp assign, partitions: {0, 1, 2, 3}, msg cnt=366
gc.ifd.result.fdp, subscribe, msg cnt=0
```

As you see using `assign()` I can read from topic with 4 partitions on all test machines, but not all messages are read.

On two machines `subscribe()` do not read any message, while on two other it reads all messages.

Is there something wrong with my code or with my environment?

---

I changed use of `poll()` according to StéphaneD. comment:

```
def count_messages(consumer):
    i = 0
    try_cnt = 0
    while True:
        records = consumer.poll(50)     # timeout in millis
        if not records:
            try_cnt += 1
            if try_cnt > 10:
                break
        for _, consumer_records in records.items():
            for _ in consumer_records:
                i += 1
    return i
```

With this change my programs seems to read all messages with both `subscribe()` and `assign()`.

Comment: When there are no records from `consumer.poll()`, do not stop yet: add a retry strategy to check at least if X `poll()` are empty in a row, then stop. I don't think there is any guarantee in Kafka that `poll` will always return something (even if you know there is something), due to Kafka broker algorithms/optimizations.

Comment: @StéphaneD. Thank you. It was problem. Can you write it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are no records from `consumer.poll()`, do not stop yet: add a retry strategy to check at least if X `poll()` are empty in a row, then stop.

I don't think there is any guarantee in Kafka that `poll()` will always return something (even if you know there is something), due to Kafka broker algorithms/optimizations.

Comment: I updated my answer with function that seems to read all messages in kafka topic. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good. Note 50ms is very low when `poll()`ing and really targets low latency requirements (more networking back-and-forth traffic). 200-500ms is more common (the broker still replies earlier because of max.poll.records (default 500), fetch.min.bytes (1), fetch.max.wait.ms (500), ...)